# Notebook does not boot from bootable USB to install Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall, dell-inspiron, laptop, scsi

I have a **Dell Inspiron Notebook** which has an **Atom processor** and which had a factory set-up of XP onto it. I had opted out the CD-ROM drive @ the time of purchase. Now my Windows XP is corrupted.

I tried installing **Windows 7** on it, but it popped some error and could not complete installation for some reason (*did not proceed from the last page where it said completing installation*).

However I have tried re-installing **XP** from a **bootable USB drive**. Still @ the time of set-up it pops up an error saying:

**CD-ROM drive not found. Set-up cannot continue. Press `F3` to exit.**

Also it displays a note that **SCSI adapter** has not been removed.

How do I go about and install XP, can it be a problem with the **bootable USB drive**, or is there a problem with my hardware?

Comment: Did the XP installation from your usb stick work?  You may check out this site http://newyear2006.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/windows-vista-windows-7-windows-xp-multiboot-usb-stick-erstellen/ there is a working tutorial about bootable xp installations, unfortunately its in german, you may have to translate ist with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need make bootable windows xp,vista,7 just you need this tools

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2009/08/27/make-a-bootable-usb-installer-for-windows-xp-vista-7-with-wint/

Offical website program :

http://wintoflash.com/home/en/

Download link

http://wintoflash.com/download/en/

But you wanna install windows 7

I really suggest this

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

that much better for windows 7 just you need iso and 4 GB or obove usb stick

That can be usefull good luck

Answer (score 1):

Often booting from USB is disabled in BIOS Setup by default for security reasons.

Take a look into your Notebook's BIOS Setup (press the shown key while booting, it might be <kbd>F2</kbd>). In your BIOS Setup find the area for bootable devices. Set the USB to bootable there.

Comment: I get a boot screen where in I can select device from which I want to boot up.From there I select USB,and then it enters set-up but gives me the error.